# Tensorflow Argmax equivalent for multilabel classification

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do evaluation of a classification Tensorflow model.

To compute the accuracy, I have the following code :

```
predictions = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32)
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=label_ids, predictions=logits)
```

It work well in single label classification, but now I want to do multilabel classification, where my labels are Array of Integers instead of Integers.

Here is an example of label `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]` that are stored in `label_ids`, and an example of predictions `[0.1, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.6, 0.2]` from the Tensor `logits`

What function should I use instead of `argmax` to do so ? (My labels are arrays of 6 Integers with value of either 0 or 1)

If needed, we can suppose that there is a threshold of 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably better to do this type of post-processing evaluation outside of tensorflow, where it is more natural to try several different thresholds.

If you want to do it in tensorflow, you can consider:

```
predictions = tf.math.greater(logits, tf.constant(0.5))
```

This will return a tensor of the original logits shape with True for all entries greater than 0.5. You can then calculate accuracy as before. This is suitable for cases where many labels can be simultaneously true for a given sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to caclutae accuracy in multiclass classification:

`tf.argmax` will return the axis where y value is `max` for both `y_pred` and `y_true`(actual y).

Further `tf.equal` is used to find total number of matches (It returns True, False).

Convert the boolean into float(i.e. 0 or 1) and use `tf.reduce_mean` to calculate the accuracy.

```
correct_mask = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1), tf.argmax(y_true,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_mask, tf.float32))
```

**Edit**

Example with data:

```
import numpy as np

y_pred = np.array([[0.1,0.5,0.4], [0.2,0.6,0.2], [0.9,0.05,0.05]])
y_true = np.array([[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]])

correct_mask = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1), tf.argmax(y_true,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_mask, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # print(sess.run([correct_mask]))
  print(sess.run([accuracy]))
```

Output:

```
[0.6666667]
```

Comment: If I understand well, for this solution to work, `y_pred` must have value of either 0 or 1 (like `y_true`) ? In my case,I have a Tensor with float values between 0 and 1. So I need to do a transformation before that (with a threshold)?

Comment: @Nakeuh Nope, you can have numeric values in your `y_pred`, it will return the axis with max value.

Comment: I want to do MultiLabel classification. Here is an example : An `y_pred` is `[0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.9]`, and an `y_true` is  `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`, in this case, the prediction is correct. I don't think we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Nakeuh I have added example